# How to understand virtual switch in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, bridge

I have a following virtual Ethernet switch in Linux:

```
root@vmhost:~# brctl show br0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.266b04c4a79a       no              eth1
                                                        tap1
                                                        tap2
root@vmhost:~#
```

`eth1` is a physical interface. Am I right that it is correct to imagine this switch in front of the server where `eth1` of this server is connected to the virtual-switch and `tap1` and `tap2` interfaces are like wires to NIC's in virtual-machines? So basically like this:

[image]

In a nutshell, all the traffic from "Internet gw" to virtual-machines or VM-host goes through this virtual-switch and all the traffic from virtual-machines or VM-host to "Internet gw" also go through this virtual-switch?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: I would rather draw the blue switch box `br0` inside the Dell PE860. And then eth1 line from that box to the internet gw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram is good except for the labels on the vertical black line between the bridge and "Dell PE860". It should really be labelled "br0", not "eth1". eth1, tap1, and tap2, having become member ports of the bridge, have been effectively relegated to the role of being layer 2 interfaces, not layer 3. IP packets sent and received from the VM-host go into and come from br0, and br0 is where the IP address gets configured.

You will notice that this means that in Linux, every bridge effectively has an additional member port beyond those listed under `interfaces` by `brctl show`: the host's own layer 3 interface to the bridge. You are familiar with Cisco. In Cisco-land, this interface is called BVI0 (or BVI1, etc...). In Cisco-land it's optional: the router may or may not participate in the bridge. In Linux, it's always present.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the drawing. So am I correct that if the frame comes from the "Internet gw" to physical `eth1` port, then it actually reaches a virtual switch `br0` and based on the destination MAC address, it is sent out from certain virtual-switch port? And if the destination MAC address of Ethernet frame is the same which is on `br0` interface, then the frame is sent to VM host `br0` interface?

Comment: That's exactly right

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! What's also common to `IRB` in Cisco devices is that Linux virtual switch is also VLAN transparent. Even QinQ transparent.